# jQuery UI resizable handle missing after upgrade jQ UI version

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I am in the process of upgrading jQuery UI from 1.8.16 to 1.10.3. After doing so, the resizable function still works, but the handle in the corner giving the visual cue that the area is resizable is missing. I made no changes to the jquery code using the UI features so far.

I have jQuery 1.7.1 but want to upgrade to 1.10.2 shortly.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, with upgrading jQuery core to 2.1.0 from 2.0.3, leaving jQuery-UI at 1.10.3.  No clues yet - will keep hunting, and maybe try upgrading jQuery-UI to 1.10.4, since it's available.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem after upgrading jQuery core to 2.1.0 from 2.0.3.  I downloaded a new version of jQuery UI v. 1.10.4 from http://jqueryui.com/download/ and tweaked the relative paths for images from `url(images/` to the appropriate path for my solution (which was `url(../Images/` ) in both the `jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css` and `jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css` files.  This seems to have fixed the problem.

I suspect a CSS issue, on your part.  To diagnose, press f12 & find the container surrounding the `textarea` control.  There will be an image url in there, which is likely not pointing properly.

Comment: This does not seem to apply, as I cannot find any references to the images. However, it does give me a hint on an alternate approach. Namely to change the border-bottom-style to dotted on the appropriate boundary, to attempt to imply resizability since I cannot get the handle to appear.

Comment: Did you try using f12 (in I.E. it'll bring up a diagnostic window, in FireFox if you have FireBug installed it'll do the same) to try to see what the container was pointing to?  It's an image, is the thing - a container is added surrounding the textarea control, with an image at the bottom-right corner.  If the reference to the image doesn't match, it'll not display anything.

Comment: First thing I always try is using Developer Tools or Firebug. No help from that.

Comment: What I see in my source for the handle div is `<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div>`.  That div gets filled with the appropriate image.  Hope you get it straightened out. :(

Comment: I opened the dialog, then checked Firebug. I was able to see similar class attributes, but not identical. I copied your class attributes, but this did not help. My theory is that the icon comes from a file and the styles no longer point to the correct place in the file.

Comment: Sounds quite reasonable, yes - although I wouldn't copy my class attributes, as those should be applied by the use of the `resizeable` script.  If you can find what the `img` tag references, then you should be able to see the path that's not right for your solution.